# How can I pull in the Rails action or controller names into my Ruby Gem for use in a log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

First question on here so go easy please. I am writing a gem for use in my rails application. The gem will simply print to a log file the information passed via the params from an action in the controller. I have this working up until the point where I would like for the report file to also print the name of the action from where the information is coming from. So example output would be:

Logged Details: date and time
Report from action: (Controller + actions name like) Profile.update and then the params information. I have it working to pull in the params information with the code below.

I have commented out the part where I thought would bring in the data for me. getting an error on it. Any advise would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
# initializes file and writes-only at end of file if exists or creates new one
def self.open(filename)
    @filename = File.open(filename,'a+')
end


# method to take in any amount of parameters and write to file
def self.usageLog (*items)
    ReportLogger.open("UsageLogging.txt")
    # string actionName = controllerContext.RouteData.values["action"].ToString()
    @filename.print("Logged Details: " + Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + "\n")
    # @filename.print("Report Action: :" + actionName)
        items.each do |item|
            @filename.print(item)
        end

        @filename.puts( " -EndLog" + "\n" + " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
    end
```

Amended - I've played about with this but couldn't seem to get it working. I've changed the controller to call ReportLogger.usageLog(profile_params) so this should pull in all the params? I've amended the Gem code like below but it doesn't seem to want to pull in the controller details to the log.

```
# method to take in any amount of parameters and write to file
def self.usageLog(params)
    ReportLogger.open("UsageLogging.txt")
    # string actionName = controllerContext.RouteData.values["action"].ToString()
    #controller_name = params["controller"]
    #action_name = params["action"]
    #other_params = params.reject do |k,v| 
    #   %w(action controller).include? k
    #end

    @filename.print("Logged Details: " + Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + "\n")
    #@filename.puts(controller_name)

    #@filename.print("Report Action: :" + controller_name)

    controller_name = params[:controller]
    @filename.puts(controller_name)

    params.each do |param|
        @filename.print(param.to_s + "\n")
    end

        @filename.puts( " -EndLog" + "\n" + " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
    end
```

Report log looks like:

Logged Details: 02/12/2015 13:11:11

["name", "Bradley"]
["phone_number", "087 6312683"]
["image", #, @original_filename="IMG_0001.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[image]\"; filename=\"IMG_0001.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]
["bio", "New feck, shit!"]
 -EndLog

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params always contain the Controller name and the Action name:

```
def index
  puts params
end
> {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
```

So if you make your usageLog method accept the whole params hash, you can just access these, like:

```
def self.usageLog(params)

  controller_name = params["controller"]
  action_name = params["action"]
  other_params = params.reject{|k,v| %w(action controller).include? k }

end
```

Then where ever you want to log from a controller, just do:

```
ReportLogger.usageLog(params)
```

Or if you want to pass in multiple arguments, you might call it this way:

```
ReportLogger.usageLog(params[:controller], params[:action], model_params, "anything else")
```

where model_params is your sanitized white list method for the model you are dealing with.

Then you would define your method like:

```
def self.usageLog(controller_name, action_name, *items)
  ....
  items.each do |item|
    @filename.print(item.to_s + "\n")
  end

end
```

Comment: If you do profile_params you will get the sanized list just of the profile subset. Consider calling it like: ReportLogger.usageLog(params) instead.

Comment: I'll have a go at this now. Thanks rlarcombe for the quick response and help.

Comment: I tweaked my answer a little bit.

Comment: That works now rlarcombe. It pulls in the params for everything and I can pull the name from this. Perfect. 

One other thing if i may as I notice if i try just call two particular params from the controller and want only them printed to the log but the amount could change so in the log i kind of need to have them undefined, like i had originally with the *params in the Gem and then loop through how many are input for logging. is this possible? I keep getting argument error (1 0) when trying this. Thanks again for the help. I understand that much more clearly now.

Comment: Hi rlarcombe. That was spot on. Got it all working and understand the process a lot better now. Thanks again. Big respect.